# How do i scroll a UITable view down until i see a cell with label "Value" in Calabash

Tags: iphone, ios, cucumber, calabash

How do i scroll a UITableView down until i see a cell with label "Value" in **Calabash/Cucumber**.
 I've been trying to do it using:

```
      Then I swipe down until I see "Value"
```

and using:

```
      Then I scroll down until I see "Value"
```

but none of them seem to work. Thanks!

The message I get when I try with the above is obviously:

> You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these
>   snippets:
>
> Then(/^I swipe down until I see "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|   pending #
>   express the regexp above with the code you wish you had end

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add step definitions

```
Then /^I scroll to cell with "([^\"]*)" label$/ do |name|
    wait_poll(:until_exists => "label text:'#{name}'", :timeout => 20) do
    scroll("tableView", :down)
    end
end
```

to the ProjectName/features/step_definitions/my_first_steps.rb ruby file and 
In your calabash script add

```
Then I scroll to cell with "AAA" label
```

its working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Every cucumber framework has a set of predefined steps. Of course, these steps don't cover all  the possibilites. If you need additional functionality, you have to define your own steps:

```
When /^I scroll (up|down) until I see "([^\"]*)"$/ do |direction, something_to_see|
   #implement the step here
end
```

I can't help you with the exact implementation (what is "Value"?) but you can find the core functions [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/blob/master/calabash-cucumber/lib/calabash-cucumber/core.rb)

Probably you'll need function

```
scroll(uiquery, direction)
```

(where `uiquery` will be `tableView`)

If you take this function and `element_is_not_hidden` you can create a `while` cycle which will scroll down until you see the "Value".

Maybe something similar to the following (I don't know Calabash but I know Frank a little)

```
When /^I scroll (up|down) until I see "([^\"]*)"$/ do |direction, something_to_see|
   max_scroll_tries = 10

   [0..max_scroll_tries].each do
      break if element_is_not_hidden("view marked:'#{something_to_see}'")
      scroll("tableView", direction)
   end

   check_element_exists_and_is_visible("view marked:'#{something_to_see}'")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

table have rows and sections, based how your code is organized use rows or sections in below code

```
def scroll_side_panel(text)

section=0
scroll_to_cell(:row => 0, :section => 0) # scroll to top of view
sleep 1 # wait for a second

#Scroll to each element and compare text, if there is a match break
each_cell(:animate => false, :post_scroll => 0.2) do |row, sec|
  puts "#{query("tableViewCell indexPath:#{row},#{sec} label", :text)}  #{text}"
  if query("tableViewCell indexPath:#{row},#{sec} label", :text).first==text
    break
  end
  section=section+1
end
puts "table view text found at element number:#{section}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

following should also work

```
Then(/^I scrolldown until "(.*?)" is visible$/) do |arg1|
  until query("lable text:'#{arg1}'").length > 0
    scroll("tableView", :down)
  end
end
```

Call this by following

```
Then I scrolldown until "XY" is visible
```