# Calabash Android Looping through a ListView to check

Tags: android, listview, calabash, calabash-android

I've just started using `Calabash` and have come across a listview.

For each listview row I want to check the presence of some text and image view.

However I'm unsure how can i loop through the listview?

Something like

```
foreach list_item in listview
   check text label with id
   check image view with id
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about using foreach in this case, but you could do it based on index number in the list.
Something like get count of item, then in a loop move through them by using of of two options

```
getListView().setSelection(21);
```

For a smooth scroll:

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(21);
```

From this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/7561660/1165581 by [HandlerExploit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713773/handlerexploit)

And then for each item check the image and text.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in my project and it works hope it helps you.

In your Scenario:

> Then I scroll to text with "xyz" label and touch it

Declare the step as follows:

```
Then /^I scroll to text with "([^\"]*)" label and touch it$/ do |name|
element="TextView text:'#{name}'"      
    if !element_exists(element)
            wait_poll(timeout: 20,
            timeout_message: 'Unable to find "Example"', :until_exists => "TextView text:'#{name}'") do
            scroll_down
     end
     if element_exists(element)
            touch element 
            sleep(10)
     else
            screenshot_and_raise "could not find the cell"
     end
     else
            touch element
            sleep(10)
     end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@userMod2 Check below solutions -

- **Solution 1**

When you use

> myList.getAdapter().getView(i,null,null)

you are getting a new instance of the item view, try the

> ListView.getChildAt(position)

method like this

```
 private void ButtonClick() {
    /** get all values of the EditText-Fields */
    View v;
    ArrayList<String> mannschaftsnamen = new ArrayList<String>();
    EditText et;
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.getCount(); i++) {
      v = myList.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
      et = (EditText) v.findViewById(i);
      mannschaftsnamen.add(et.getText().toString());
    }
    // Add your action code here
    // Add your action code here
 }
```

- **Solution 2**

  ```
  public void onScroll(AbsListView v, int firstVisibleItem, int   visibleCount, int totalItemCount)
  {
  ListView lv = this.getListView();
  int childCount = lv.getChildCount();

  for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
  {
      View v = lv.getChildAt(i);
      TextView tx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
      tx.setTextSize(textSize);
  }
  }
  ```